# CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When I try to build my app, I'm getting the below error

```
❌  (node_modules/expo-dev-launcher/ios/EXRCTAppDelegateInterceptor.mm:63:15)

  61 | {
  62 | #if __has_include(<RNReanimated/REAInitializer.h>) && !RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
> 63 |   reanimated::REAInitializer(bridge);
     |               ^ no type named 'REAInitializer' in namespace 'reanimated'
  64 | #endif // __has_inclide(<RNReanimated/REAInitializer.h>) && !RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
  65 | 
  66 |   return [super jsExecutorFactoryForBridge:bridge];
```

I have already tried removing the `node_modules` by

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

But I still get the error. Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.